# python - align time steps of two data sets

Tags: python, dataset, alignment

As a python newbie I need a little help. I have two files with temperature data values. The first file contains values with time steps of 2 seconds. (but sometimes even seconds and sometimes uneven seconds). The second file contains values with time steps of 2.5 minutes (180 seconds). 
How do I align the two data sets, so that I can do correlation analyses?

Help is very much appreciated. I now do not know what code to post, I think you all understand what I need. If not, so please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: resample your data to 1 seconds. If the second file contains data that doesn't change much - which it doesn't, I assume, hence the 2,5 min sampling interval - you don't even have to interpolate, just take the last value for all new time points.

Comment: give us the first few lines of each dataset in your OP, please.

Comment: thank you very much for you quick answer. but how would that look in code-language? :)

Comment: First file (2 sec.; this one only contains the temperature values, but the time steps are 2 sec.): `4.5654
5.3445
6.345`

Second file (2.5 mins): `"No.","Date Time, CET","Temp, °C"
1,01/01/15 12:00:00 PM,4.740
2, 01/01/15 12:02:30 PM,4.856`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `spicy::interp1d` to do the interpolation for you.

A general example is

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
f = interp1d(x, y)
xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, 'x')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot showing original x,y and interpolated xnew,ynew]

so in your case you have `x` and `y` from your data, define a new `xnew = np.arange(MIN, MAX, 1)` where your steps are in seconds. Make certain that you cast the sample of the second file into seconds, not minutes. You will then have `xnew,ynew` to work with for each file.

Comment: thanks @Shawn Mehan. but I am not quiet sure if I understand what you have postet :( can you apply this to my data?